# Using wire and assign vs. wire in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Is there any difference between

```
wire A = B & C;
```

and

```
wire A;
assign A = B & C;
```

?
I do not think so but I have seen code using the latter and I wonder if that was done for a reason.

Comment: they are identical

Comment: Identical. I would go for the latter and split assignment with declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are functionally the same in your example. There are slight differences when adding a delay to a wire declaration.

```
wire #5 A = B & C;

wire A;
assign #5 A = B & C;
```

In the first form, the delay gets added to all other net drivers. You can also use SDF back annotation to modify the wire delay.

In the second form, the delay applies to only that continuous assignment, and you cannot use SDF back annotation to modify the delay.

My observation is that most people use the second form in RTL to keep the declarations and functionality separated.